# SPD07 - How to change a add style in Email content

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server

I want to add font-style in Define E-mail Message Content.

**How to do this**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add similar code in your mail body

```
<style type="text/css">    
    P.FontStyle
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

use the class name in your mail content.

For Ex.

```
<p class="FontStyle">Hello User</p>,<br/>
<p> Your other body text goes here</p>
```

So finally your code should look like

```
<style type="text/css">    
    P.FontStyle
    {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<p class="FontStyle">Hello User</p>,<br/>
<p> Your other body text goes here</p>
```

Your mail will look like

> **Hello User**,
>
> Your other body text goes here

Answer (score 2):

**Design the HTML needed in the body**

- Create a new HTML page from File > New > HTML.
- In the new pane, select Split view from the bottom left corner of the screen.

**There are two considerations when you use HTML in workflows :**

***Consideration 1***

- Workflow e-mails do not support class-based styles. All the formatting **must be done using inline styles**.
- If you format the message text in Code view and Design view, you must set Style Application to Manual so that SPD 2007 does not add CSS classes, which the server cannot render in workflow mail.
- Make sure that Style Application is set to Manual and the Target Rule is set to New Inline Style.

***Consideration 2***

- Any white space will affect how the designed HTML will be displayed. So it is recommended to remove it.
- This can be done easily by performing these steps:
- Click Tools > Optimize HTML.
- In the Remove Whitespace section, select HTML all whitespace.
- Click OK.
- All the whitespace should be removed from the HTML code in the Code Pane.
- To get the formatted text again, Select the text in the Code Pane > right-click > reformat HTML.

Please follow below mentioned URLs for better understanding.

[Send a basic and formatted e-mail message from a workflow](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2010/12/10/send-a-basic-and-formatted-e-mail-message-from-a-workflow/)

[Creating HTML Emails with SPD Workflows](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/03/14/creating-html-emails-with-spd-workflows-aspx/)